# Cant upgrade docker compose in Ubuntu16 in a VM

Tags: ubuntu, docker-compose

23/09/16 - docker-compose version 1.5.2, Docker v 1.12.1

I've looked at updating docker compose as I get an error on `up` with the service `version: '2'`

I've tried:

https://gist.github.com/wdullaer/f1af16bd7e970389bad3

https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I downloaded the run.sh file under the latest release fix list from https://github.com/docker/compose/releases

Go to where the file has downloaded to and

```
chmod +x run.sh

sh ./run.sh
```